# Javascript Click Not Presenting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to display a lightbox when a button in my HTML is pressed.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="login-signup">
        <h1> Need to sign in or register? </h1>
             <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#" class="load">SIGN IN</a>
                <a href="#" class="add">REGISTER</a>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

When Sign In is pressed, I want my lightbox to present. I've tried to do this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
      $('.login-signup .buttons').click(function(e) {

    $('.sign-in').lightbox_me({

    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" isn't particularly useful. Can you elaborate? I assume nothing happens visually, but what errors are you seeing, either in Firebug or the native developer tools in whatever browser you're testing in?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you don't have any elements in your DOM with class attribute "sign-in" ?

What's the result of this ?

```
$('.load').click(function(e) {

   alert($(".sign-in").length);

});
```

If it's 0 then that means that you don't have any elements in your DOM with class="sign-in" and your lightbox thing probably can't do anything on an element that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific button to fire, in this case it is your SIGN IN button, then use the assigned class like so:

```
$('.load').click(function(e) {
    $('.sign-in').lightbox_me({
    });
});
```

[More information](http://api.jquery.com/click/)